# Missed timestamp in Boost.Log

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

I'm new in Boost.Log. I'd like to print out data in the following format:
`[TimeStamp][Severity] Message`.

I have such code

```
auto my_formatter = [](boost::log::record_view const& rec, boost::log::formatting_ostream& strm)
{
    strm << "[" << boost::log::expressions::format_date_time< boost::posix_time::ptime >("TimeStamp", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") << "]";
    strm << "[" << rec[boost::log::trivial::severity] << "] ";
    strm << rec[boost::log::expressions::smessage];
};

void addFileSink()
{
    using sinkType = boost::log::sinks::synchronous_sink<boost::log::sinks::text_file_backend>;

    auto backend = boost::make_shared<boost::log::sinks::text_file_backend>(
        boost::log::keywords::file_name = "log_%N.log",
        boost::log::keywords::rotation_size = 10 * 1024 * 1024,
        boost::log::keywords::open_mode = std::ios_base::app
    );

    boost::shared_ptr<sinkType> sink(new sinkType(backend));
    sink->set_formatter(my_formatter);
    sink->set_filter(boost::log::trivial::severity >= boost::log::trivial::severity_level::info);
    boost::log::core::get()->add_sink(sink);
}

void addConsoleSink()
{
    using sinkType = boost::log::sinks::synchronous_sink<boost::log::sinks::text_ostream_backend>;

    auto backend = boost::make_shared<boost::log::sinks::text_ostream_backend>();
    backend->add_stream(boost::shared_ptr<std::ostream>(&std::cout, boost::null_deleter()));
    backend->auto_flush(true);

    boost::shared_ptr<sinkType> sink(new sinkType(backend));
    sink->set_formatter(my_formatter);
    sink->set_filter(boost::log::trivial::severity >= boost::log::trivial::severity_level::error);
    boost::log::core::get()->add_sink(sink);
}

int main()
{
    boost::log::add_common_attributes();

    addFileSink();
    addConsoleSink();

    boost::log::sources::severity_logger<boost::log::trivial::severity_level> lg;

    BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, boost::log::trivial::severity_level::error) << "Message error";
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, boost::log::trivial::severity_level::info) << "Message info";

    return 0;
}
```

It works fine beside of TimeStamp attribute, I'm getting such output:

`[[error] Message error`

I've tried different ways from examples and so on, but I can't find solution for this problem.. 
`boost::log::add_common_attributes();` doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boost::log::expressions::format_date_time` is not a function to format date and time. It is a *formatter generator* to be used in lambda formatting expressions. In other words, `format_date_time` creates a formatter (a function object with a specific signature), which, upon calling, will extract the attribute value from the log record and format it.

You should either use lambda expressions to build the formatter instead of your `my_formatter` function, in which case you can use `format_date_time`, or use one of the traditional methods of formatting date and time, like [`strftime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime) or [Boost.DateTime IO](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html).

Example of using the lambda expressions:

```
namespace expr = boost::log::expressions;

sink->set_formatter
(
    expr::stream
        << "[" << expr::format_date_time< boost::posix_time::ptime >("TimeStamp", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") << "]"
        << "[" << boost::log::trivial::severity << "] "
        << expr::smessage
);
```

Example of using `strftime`:

```
auto my_formatter = [](boost::log::record_view const& rec, boost::log::formatting_ostream& strm)
{
    if (auto timestamp = boost::log::extract< boost::posix_time::ptime >("TimeStamp", rec))
    {
        std::tm ts = boost::posix_time::to_tm(*timestamp);

        char buf[128];
        if (std::strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &ts) > 0)
            strm << "[" << buf << "]";
    }

    strm << "[" << rec[boost::log::trivial::severity] << "] ";
    strm << rec[boost::log::expressions::smessage];
};
```

Comment: The Boost lamba expression above also fails to output a timestamp for me (on boost 1.65.1 at least).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I resolved this issue:

```cpp
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(timestamp, "timestamp", boost::posix_time::ptime);
// ....
logging::formatter fmt =
    expr::stream << expr::format_date_time(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
                 << /* ... */ ;
```

using this formatter on sinks provided me with timestamps